# Restrict document types for only PDF and Word documents

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, uidocumentmenuviewcontroller

I'm using the `UIDocumentMenuViewController` to pick and choose documents. I want to restrict users to pick only .pdf and .docx files.

I know I can allow only PDFs like this.

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
```

But how do I include `.docx` types as well?

Comment: Hint: `documentTypes` takes an array.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, but I can't find the correct constant for word documents. I'm wondering if one exists.

Comment: Did you try to use UIDocumentPickerViewController? UIDocumentMenuViewController is deprecated